# Reopening “Create Root Category in magento programatically”

Tags: discussion

I voted to reopen the below question. Reason is:

**Question is clear in my point of view ,Only that does not have any code?.**

That does not means it's unclear.

If any body is agree with me then must put his/her reopen vote

Question link: [Create Root Category in magento programatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/83749/4564)

Comment: you are right. question is clear and evident, eventhough it does not provide any codes.

Comment: The question was reopened. thank you for the heads up.